# Поставлена задача, обратиться на свитч через телнет

Tags: java, telnet

(я работаю на провайдера в тех поддержке, есть доступ на свитчи некоторых городов)
Задача такая: обратиться на свитч( DES-3552), вывести в консоль текст, который вернул мне свитч. Конкретный, у меня справишвает "Username:"
В консоль выводит в кривой кодировке. Пробовал перекодировать при выводе, использовал разные вариации. Может знаете, какую кодировку использует телнет? Может вообще другие классы или методы использовать?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Socket socket = null;
socket = new Socket("10.101.225.33",23);
BufferedReader  dis = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())));
String msg = dis.readLine();
System.out.println(new String(msg.getBytes(),"KOI8-U"));//тут пробовал разные варианты. И так тоже пробовал getBytes("cp1251"),"windows-1251");
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас из сокета идет набор байт, представляющий строку в какой-то кодировке. `readLine` считает, что этот набор байт представляет собой строку в UTF-16 кодировке, что неверно. Поэтому все Ваши последующие манипуляции с перекодированием не имеют никакого эффекта

Вам из сокета нужно читать не строку, а именно набор байт. Поэтому вместо

```
dis.readLine();
```

используйте

```
dis.read();
```

и полученный набор байт собирайте в строку, согласно нужной кодировки

Comment: Извините, не совсем уверен, что понимаю о чём Вы. Можете мне дать ссылку на статью, где я узнаю об этом?

Comment: @ЕгоркаШатохин расширил ответ